# Creating nested list for the list containing more than 2 items in the sub list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a list with sub list containing more than 2 items for each list item. I am able to create the list but not the sub list for the items inside the list.Basically my idea is to create a code to filter the number of elements in the sub list and create dynamic list when the list is loaded.

For example

```
Listitem1
sublistitem1
Listitem2
Listitem3
sublistitem1
sublistitem2
sublistitem3
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far and provide some code samples.

Comment: <Grid>   
<ListView Grid.Row=0 x:Name="parentlist" ItemSource={Binding parentlist}>
<Grid>
<---Some element at row 0--!>
<ListView Grid.Row=1 Background="Transparent" x:Name="Nestedingredient" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Visible"  ItemsSource="{Binding childlist}">
 </ListView>      
</Grid>                                             
  </ListView>     
</Grid>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var myList = new List<List<string>>();
myList.Add(new List<string>() { "sublistitem1" });
myList.Add(new List<string>());
myList.Add(new List<string>() { "sublistitem1", "sublistitem2", "sublistitem3" });
```

To get those with 2 or more sublistitems...

```
var myListWith2OrMoreSubItems = myList.Where(x => x.Count >= 2).ToList();
```

You need a `using System.Linq;` at the top.

Comment: Thank you, But I have list already with the sublist items in it. I have to bind those items depending on the number of sublistitems in the list.For example : if Listitem1 has more than 2 elements then it should show the subitems for that listitem. If it has 1 subitem it should not

Comment: You're welcome @MonicaKamble. Please mark the answer as helpful and as the correct answer if you would like to give me credit